# Google AppEngine custom 404 dynamic page

Tags: google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, administration

I want to set custom 404 page and admin zone in /dev/ path , so I have this app.yaml:

```
application: appengine_app
version: 0-00-1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:    

- url: /dev/.*
  script: dispatch.py
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: dispatch.py
```

with next code

```
app = webapp.WSGIApplication( [ ('/dev/analyze', AnalyzePage)
                              , ('/.*', NotFoundPage) ]
                              , debug=False )
```

On local machine all is ok. But when I try to GET **/dev/analyze** on Production server it redirects to **/_ah/login_required?continue=http://appengine_app.appspot.com/dev/analyze** and it catched by **NotFoundPage**. So I can not use admin part on Production. Can I has dynamic 404 page and admin part of site?

**UPD**: if I switch off NotFoundPage and try to GET **/dev/analyze** on Production server it redirects to **/_ah/login_required?continue=http://appengine_app.appspot.com/dev/analyze** and response with 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You've set the script handle in `app.yaml` to admin-only, which means the runtime will ensure you're logged in as an admin before it sends requests to your code. There's no way for the runtime to know that the page will result in a 404 - and this is plausibly something you may not even want non-admin users to discover.

If it's important that you send 404s to users who aren't signed in, you can either make the handler in app.yaml more specific - eg, make it match only `/dev/analyze` - or you can shift the admin check into your code.

Comment: I set Federated Login for my app, but not set login page handler. I thought some exists by default. When I switch to Google Accounts API and GET /dev/analyze it show default login page and all goes as planned

Comment: @whalebot I'm not sure I understand. What's the problem, then? Can't you just create a login page handler and set it to not require login?